# How can the temprance movement prevent the moral degradation of American society by stigmatizing distilled spirits?

Tags: society, government, politics

The United States of America has experienced a moral decline in recent years, straying from its Puritan values as a Christian nation and has become a modern day Sodom and Gomorrah. The nonsense of Gen Zers on Tik Tok, to the terrible finale of GOT, to the election of President Kardashian to the oval office, all share a common link: alcohol. These beverages have sent America reeling into a state of depravity and excess. The temperance movement foresaw this decades ago at the beginning of the 20th century, where they actively pushed for the elimination of alcohol to ameliorate poverty and various societal issues. This led to the creation of the 18th amendment, which banned the sale, distribution, and consumption of alcohol. This era of Prohibition ushered in the golden age of gangsters, in which the underworld preyed on the sinful desires of the populace by keeping them well supplied with the substance. This turned otherwise decent folk into criminals, completely undermining the movement's goals. This despicable behavior by the citizenry led to the repeal of the amendment, and the noble cause ended in failure.

For alcohol to be discouraged, it needs to gain the social stigma of other drugs, such as cocaine, weed, or cigarettes. In the 50s and 60s, cigarette companies successfully marketed tobacco products to the populace to increase their profits. Decades of anti-tobacco campaigns alerting individuals to the dangers of smoking have turned the habit into a pariah, as smokers today are widely shamed for their wretched addictions. It stands to reason that the same methods would work for alcohol. The negative effects of alcohol are widely known, including its links to certain issues in society, such as drunk driving, domestic abuse, and other societal problems. However, people continue to frequent bars to become intoxicated, often attending events known as " happy hours" in which sellers of the product entice their customers to drunkenness by offering cheaper prices. This shameless and despicable leads the citizenry into  decadence as society descends further and further into sin.

The temperance movement need to protect the virtue of America by turning the populace away from liquors and toward serving the will of God. How can they go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you want to draw a hard line between distilled spirits and non-distilled drinks, like beer and wine?

Comment: It's worth noting that cigarettes' positive effects are vastly outweighed by their negative health effects, while alcohol, in moderation, has salutary health effects.  So "lying" is probably a starting point.

Comment: It should be noted that the stigma of hard drugs has ruined millions of lives and caused the deaths of hundreds of thousands, not to mention wasted trillions of dollars of tax revenue and given rise to an authoritarian police state that won't be easily dismantled. You might discover this for yourself someday OP, when they put the wrong address on a middle-of-the-night no-knock warrant and grenade your baby or kill your dog. I like alternate history fiction, but some experiments are so thorough in the real world that we already know how badly it'd work out.

Comment: Consumption of alcohol was never outlawed in the US. The restrictions were on production and sale. An individual could brew for their own use.

Comment: Aye, ban the Booze.. It's just competing for the market with the cracked cocainated bathsalts industry, anyways!

Comment: @DrMcCleod "An individual could brew for their own use" - citation needed.

Comment: "Homebrewing was federally legalized in 1978 for the first time since Prohibition made it illegal in 1919."  https://www.brewersassociation.org/press-releases/homebrewing-officially-legal-in-all-50-states/

Comment: Been there, done that. Didn't work, and caused a lot of problems that we're still dealing with a century later.  Downvoted because "Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results." - Frequently misattributed to Albert Einstein.

Comment: @Alexander https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition_in_the_United_States "Private ownership and consumption of alcohol were not made illegal under federal law"

Comment: @DrMcCleod - ownership and consumption, but not production. Distillation, AFAIK, was universally banned during prohibition.

Comment: America is not a Christian nation. The law that says America is not a Christian nation is literally the first amendment. The authors could not have put it any sooner.

Comment: @CharlieHershberger Yes, they could have put it earlier, such as in the constitution itself, rather than as an afterthought into an amendment.

Answer (score 9):

Stigmatizing alcohol consumption will solve nothing, it will only drive consumption underground, as did the 18th amendment.  People will buy liquor from criminals again, not because it's illegal, but because they're afraid to be seen in a liquor store.  Liquor stores will close, too, and groceries (where legal) will stop carrying beer and wine; dry counties (and even states) will proliferate, and it'll be 1925 again.

People who *have to have a drink* will get one (or several), by hook or by crook.  Meanwhile, however, instead of being a symptom, alcohol use will become a *cause* of mental health issues -- people will become depressed because they're ashamed to want alcohol.  They'll become paranoid because they're afraid someone identified them buying it.

They'll poison themselves and others trying to make their own.

It's bad enough having a Kardashian in the White House -- don't make those who would be social drinkers into deeply damaged individuals.

Answer (score 4):

### Frame Challenge: Moral degeneration of American Society does not Significantly Correlate with Alcohol Abuse

Moral Degeneration as a broad term is a really hard term to pin down, but since your question equates moral degeneracy to turning away from God, I will use Atheisms statistics to as the metric for "Moral Degeneration" in the US.

[From 2007-2019, the rate of people who identify as Atheist or Agnostic in the United States went up by about 125%](https://www.pewforum.org/2019/10/17/in-u-s-decline-of-christianity-continues-at-rapid-pace/).

[During that same period, the per capita consumption of alcohol only went up by about 3%](https://www.statista.com/statistics/442818/per-capita-alcohol-consumption-of-all-beverages-in-the-us/).

In fact, the highest per capita alcohol consumption in the US's recent history was back in 1990 at 2.45 gal/yr before modern atheisms really started to trend.  Alcohol consumption is also documented to have a positive correlation with wealth (meaning the more money you have the more you can afford to drink), yet, since 1990 alcohol consumption has grown slower than average household incomes indicating an overall negative stigma towards drinking has existed since 1990 compared to previous decades.

[image]

So it actually stands to reason that Alcohol consumption either has a NULL correlation with godlessness or possibly even an inverse one.

From what I've personally seen in my lifetime, alcohol consumption seems more likely to lead to a godly life than sobriety.  It is only when a person finds themself in a situation where they can not save themself that they are they forced to turn towards divine salvation.  So, if you encourage people to drink until they ruin thier lives, they are more likely to turn to God than if they never needed his influence ([See Step 3 in Alcoholics Anonymous](https://www.alcohol.org/alcoholics-anonymous/))

Comment: There's also the fact that "moral degeneracy" is a matter of opinion. We can also find plenty of examples of "godly" people condoning or participating in things that most of us might consider immoral.

Answer (score 2):

### A return to righteousness and a rejection of sin

It is not alcohol which is the problem, alcohol addiction is a symptom of a sick society. It is not enough to simply impose a moral framework upon the population; legislation alone cannot change what is in a person's heart. If a man craves something sinful then no legislation will quell this craving, no social stigma will turn his mind from sin. A man obsessed will do anything to satisfy his urges - he will deal with the mafia, he will rob, cheat, swindle, he will even murder if his desire is strong enough.

**It is the desire to sin, first and foremost, which is the cause of sin**

In order to eliminate sin we must eliminate the desire at it's root, in order to save a person we must keep his mind from sinful desire in the first place.

We must therefore forbid the praise of sinful behaviour and the public display of sinful behaviour. Starting in childhood, the citizenry must have upstanding role models who are free from vice. TV can no longer show any "entertainment" which glorifies sin and leads the mind to distraction. There can be no promotion of violence, drugs, or alcohol anywhere. The law alone cannot save a man who has already fallen into sin, but it can act to help prevent children from being exposed to material which sows the seeds for sinful behaviour later in life.

The internet must be strictly controlled to protect children from depravity; pornography and violence must be prohibited, such material desensitises the mind and makes it more vulnerable to acceptance of further sinful behaviour. There is no such thing as harmless erotica or harmless horror, when a child is exposed to these things - even things which are considered "pg" and "harmless" - it conditions their mind into incrementally accepting more and more harmful thoughts.

Strong-minded and upstanding members of society will volunteer as internet marshalls and patrol the darker corners of the internet, reporting harmful material and helping families whose children have been drawn towards these unhealthy behaviours. Seriously offending web sites will be shut down. There will be no social media as we k ow it today, this social media allows dark forces to manipulate the fabric of society & hijack the social dialogue which should be taking place in the real world, between friends and family. We must gain control of social media and ensure that it is only used to build healthy communities, not to disrupt them.

**This is not a problem which can be solved in just a few years**

*It took generations for society to fall, it will take generations to cleanse society*

We cannot save all children from being exposed to harmful material, but we can save some. For the next generation, God willing, we will be able to save more children from taking up the path of sin. This is how it must progress - methodically, one step at a time, each day another step forward no matter how small. The principle is that we must move things forward one step at a time, we must discourage vice strongly but we must not allow dark forces to seize control of the narrative by attempting to move too quickly.

We are attempting to delete certain modes of behaviour from the collective consciousness, this simply cannot be done in a day.

**The path to rehabilitation**

Society as a whole is sick and society as a whole needs rehabilitation, but this can mean very different things for different people.

For adults who have fallen into a path of sin and want to come back but cannot find the strength, we can offer help. We can offer rehabilitation in the form of retreats, meditation classes and guided study. We can build sanctuaries for those who have a long path to recovery, places where they will be looked after by right-minded citizens and where their demons will not be welcome to come and disturb them. Some sanctuaries will also serve as hospitals where patients can be admitted for detoxification and therapy, either by their own free choice or by appeal for intervention from close friends or family.

**Dealing with sinful behaviour**

We must come to terms with the fact that there will inevitably be a large number of people who will not, or cannot, put down their vices and come clean. The kindest thing we can offer those people is a safe place where they can indulge in their behaviour whilst minimising harm to themselves and the rest of society. We must make a place in this world for them also; they are also human and it is not our place and nor is it within our power to change their minds if they are so committed.

Therefore we should provide them with another type of sanctuary or designated district; an area which is designed to keep the demons *in*. In these areas we will make all drugs and alcohol freely available, there will be no mafia running anything but people living in such areas could be exposed to their vices day in and day out - as they have made their decision there is no sense in interfering with it. People who want drink and drugs can visit a designated area with a special pass, but if they exhibit the behavioural patterns of addiction then our system will flag them for an intervention, wherein they will be offered help and asked to make their choice. We will of course use the opportunity to minister to the population of these areas in the hope of reaching some of them & those who ask for help will always be taken to a sanctuary where they will be protected from sinful behaviours.

Obviously such people are in no fit state to raise children, so all such people would need to be surgically sterilised and their children, if they have any, placed with strong foster families who can give them the best chance in life.

There can be no children permitted in the sanctuaries of sin. By this method we can at least contain the harm and prevent it from being passed on to another generation.

**________________________________**

*As an alternative to a theocracy where you're still allowed to be a junkie, good quality of life actually results in the disappearance of addiction - see the "rat park" experiment:* https://www.psychiatrictimes.com/view/what-does-rat-park-teach-us-about-addiction

Comment: This seems like a very valid answer from the standpoint of a horror story.  "Once we've taken away all your freedoms, you'll live a perfect life."  Has my life crystal turned red yet?

Answer (score 1):

[Disulfiram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disulfiram) is a known molecule which causes dislike toward alcohol

> Disulfiram (sold under the trade name Antabuse) is a drug used to support the treatment of alcohol use disorder by producing an acute sensitivity to ethanol (drinking alcohol). Disulfiram works by inhibiting the enzyme acetaldehyde dehydrogenase, causing many of the effects of a hangover to be felt immediately following alcohol consumption. Disulfiram plus alcohol, even small amounts, produces flushing, throbbing in the head and neck, a throbbing headache, respiratory difficulty, nausea, copious vomiting, sweating, thirst, chest pain, palpitation, dyspnea, hyperventilation, fast heart rate, low blood pressure, fainting, marked uneasiness, weakness, vertigo, blurred vision, and confusion.

Add it, or a molecule with similar effect and less side effects, to the water supply of the whole country, and whoever happens to drink that water will develop a repulsion to alcohol.

Comment: As Robert A. Heinlein once wrote (in the voice of Hugh Farnham): Antabuse doesn't take away the craving, it just makes you deathly ill if you do drink.  This answer ignores the basic rule that an addict will do *anything* for their fix.  Look at what smokers endure, the risks junkies take, and so forth.  Antabuse won't solve the problem, it'll make it worse by ensuring that even a couple drinks of an evening result in a sick day.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Antabuse makes you sick before you get to have a good time.  This allows your body to be classically conditioned against it because it creates a strong stimulus > response learning mechanism that you don't get with delayed punishment like you get with a normal hangover...  that said, if you condition away alcoholism but don't address the thing that makes people WANT to turn to alcohol, they will just use other drugs instead.

Comment: Also, adding a drug to the water supply, regardless of its ethical state (poor, IMO), will be largely ineffective in rural America.  I live in North Carolina, at the end of an hour commute from my job; I and all my neighbors have wells -- and it would be a very hazardous job to try to install dosing devices on all wells in rural areas in much of the United States.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon: "...it would be a very hazardous job..." Nice bit of understatement there :-)  Then there's also the cost-effectiveness: only a small fraction of the water supply (I'd guess well under 1%) is used for drinking.  Most is used for washing, irrigation, &c.  And then there's the environmental effects of the chemicals...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Nosajimiki's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/205987/78906) and I would like to add to their frame challenge.

#### Alcohol-use disorders are already stigmatised to the same extent as heavy drugs (cocaine, heroin, etc.) and this stigma does not produce the results the OP wants.

[Cross-cultural](https://academic.oup.com/alcalc/article/46/2/105/198339) [studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3980578/) show that alcohol-use disorders are stigmatised more than any other mental illness with the extent of stigma comparable only to drug use disorders. [Studies of the US population](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/09/100915080437.htm) show that despite efforts to popularise medical explanations for mental illnesses and substance-use disorders (and wider acceptance of these explanations) the stigma is not diminished and in some cases even increases (between 1996 and 2006):

> In 2006, 67% of the public attributed major depression to neurobiological causes, compared with 54% in 1996. High proportions of respondents endorsed treatment, with general increases in the proportion endorsing treatment from doctors and specific increases in the proportions endorsing psychiatrists for treatment of alcohol dependence (from 61% in 1996 to 79% in 2006) and major depression (from 75% in 1996 to 85% in 2006). Social distance and perceived danger associated with people with these disorders did not decrease significantly. Holding a neurobiological conception of these disorders increased the likelihood of support for treatment but was generally unrelated to stigma. Where associated, the effect was to increase, not decrease, community rejection. ([study](https://ajp.psychiatryonline.org/doi/full/10.1176/appi.ajp.2010.09121743))

> [...] sociomoral conceptions of alcohol dependence were either largely unchanged or, for attributions of “bad character,” significantly increased (from 49% to 65%; F=13.50, p<0.001). Findings were largely unaffected by the addition of controls for respondents' age, sex, education, and race (Ibid.)

> A majority of the public continued to express an unwillingness to work closely with the person in the vignette (62% for schizophrenia, 74% for alcohol dependence), socialize with the person (52% for schizophrenia, 54% for alcohol dependence), or have the person marry into their family (69% for schizophrenia, 79% for alcohol dependence). In fact, significantly more respondents in the 2006 survey than the 1996 survey reported an unwillingness to have someone with schizophrenia as a neighbor (from 34% to 45%; F=6.31, p=0.01) or to have someone with alcohol dependence marry into their family (from 70% to 79%; F=4.01, p=0.05). Furthermore, a majority again reported that the vignette character with schizophrenia or alcohol dependence would likely be violent toward others.

The social stigma often results in:

- social isolation and discrimination against those suffering from alcohol-use disorders (this is also true for heavy drinkers) and their family members;
- poorer mental health outcomes for alcoholics/heavy drinkers and their families;
- lower quality medical services due to the negative biases held by medical personnel;
- alcoholics/heavy drinkers' reluctance to ask for help;
- self-stigma that may lead to depression and further alcohol abuse;
- attempts to hide dependence on alcohol which lead to guilt and associated mental problems.

All of these are counter-productive and will undermine the OP's goal '*to protect the virtue of America by turning the populace away from liquors and toward serving the will of God*'.

**The social stigma in the US is not limited to alcohol-use disorders**. It is just hidden better and leads to self-contradictory drinking culture.

For example, many TV series targeting high-schoolers and young adults would show parties with binge drinking and aggressive drinking games (parents-left-for-a-weekend parties or dormitories parties) which show that there is a cultural expectation that people of this age will drink. However, the legal drinking age in the US is 21, which makes drinking in high school illegal (and this is also often portrayed in said series). Most US universities also prohibit alcohol use on their campuses and may have disciplinary measures to punish students caught drunk (up to expulsion if the drinkers are underaged).

There are also cultural expectations of drinking (including hard liquor) during big holidays, weddings, funerals, and similar occasions. Participants may be forced to drink, yet, those who get drunk will be stigmatised. There is also an increase in solitary drinking, behind closed doors, especially among women (and portrayals of this kind of drinking in media). And despite the number of public drinking places, such as bars, decreasing the alcohol consumption goes up. Check this [interesting article](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2021/07/america-drinking-alone-problem/619017/) in *The Atlantic* about the evolution of drinking habits in the US.

---

#### What would be a better approach?

Destigmatisation of drinking and alcoholism would be a good start. This would increase social support for those who suffer from alcohol-use disorders and decrease the chances of relapse.

A more sensible, less self-contradicting drinking culture might also be a good solution. It might be better if alcohol consumption started at home where adults can supervise younger generations and demonstrate good drinking habits.

As for policy measures, the [WHO recommends these as the most cost-effective](https://www.euro.who.int/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/160680/e96457.pdf):

> There is now a substantial evidence base of systematic reviews and meta-analyses which show that policies that regulate the environment in which alcohol is marketed (particularly its price and availability) are effective in reducing alcohol-related harm. Enforced legislative measures to reduce drinking and driving and interventions directed individually towards at-risk drinkers are also effective. On the other hand, school-based education is found not to reduce alcohol-related harm, although public information and educational programmes have a role in providing information and in increasing attention to and acceptance of alcohol on the political and public agendas. Making alcohol more expensive and less available are highly cost-effective strategies to reduce harm. Banning alcohol advertising, introducing drink–driving countermeasures and directing individual interventions to at-risk drinkers are also cost-effective. In countries with relatively high levels of unrecorded production and consumption, an increase in the proportion of alcohol that is taxed may be a more effective pricing policy than a simple increase in tax. (p.109)

In addition to these, any policies that improve overall population well-being should decrease the dangers of alcohol abuse, since stress and anxiety are some of the biggest drivers behind it.

---

I am unable to offer any insights regarding 'serving the will of God' as I avoid any religious debates and do not have a proper understanding of this area.

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise of this question is flawed. Throughout history, there has been almost no correlation between "morals" (as defined by such religions) and economic success. There is almost a negative correlation.

Most "moralistic" religions flourish most when there is an economic collapse. For example, the Taliban grew because of the economic collapse of that country. In ancient Israel, the similar king Josiah had his "reform" after a near total collapse of the economy.

When we look at the results of trying to live a moralistic life as defined by such religions, we rarely find economic success. Far more often, we find a near subsistence level living. It begs the question of is this really what God wants for them?

Economic success happens far more often when pirates and thieves start following a minimal legal system. Examples include Venice, Hong Kong, and the Dutch ports. (We can also argue about the United States and Australia, both of which had a large number of prisoners dumped on them.)

So, one can argue that God does not want strict control over the population as this question suggests. Instead, God may only want a minimal change of heart (like what is implied in Jeremiah 17:19-27.)

Instead of the "virtue of America", it can be argued that the ideals of freedom and dignity are more important.

Comment: Of course one could argue that "god" (the deity of any monotheistic religion) actually likes people to be miserable.  Indeed, most "virtue" seems to be equated with abstaining from enjoyable pastimes, AKA "sin".

Answer (score -1):

There are two types of stigmatization:

One into a free country and other inside a closed one (a dictatorship).

Inside a dictatorship stigmatization works because people have no choice. It is a mater of cop with the idea or being sent to a GULAG.

Free countries are different. You have free speech a several other way to protest against a "dogma".

Indeed in free countries stigmatization works
in reverse. Example:

No one was paying attention to this book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Da_Vinci_Code
until Catholic Church and other religious designations stigmatized it and placed it into a "no no" list.

Today it is a commercial success.

> The temperance movement need to protect the virtue of America by turning the populace away from liquors and toward serving the will of God. How can they go about accomplishing this?

If you are serious about this I think stigmatization is not the way.

I bet group therapy is a best approach.